# Avoid memory leakage when removing object pointer from the map

Tags: c++, dictionary, pointers, std, stdmap

I create an `object_ptr` and insert it into a `std::map`. Then in a different part of the code, I find the object using the key and erase the value from the map and delete the object.

There seems to be a Memory-leak though, how can I find and fix it?

```
void foo(){
    Request * req = new Request();
    MyMap.insert (std::pair<int, Request *> (address, req));
    bar(address);
}
void bar(int address){
  map<int, Request*>::iterator it_req = MyMap.find(address);
  MyMap.erase(it_req);
  delete it_req->second;
}
```

Comment: By not using raw pointer as `mapped_type`.

Comment: Swap the `delete` and `erase` lines.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
MyMap.erase(it_req); 
delete it_req->second;
```

Once you have `erase`d the element, that iterator is no longer valid. You can't dereference it to get the pointer to `delete`. The simplest solution is just to reverse these two lines: `delete` *then* `erase`.

However, a better approach is to not have to `delete` at all. Do you really need to dynamically allocate the `Request`? Can you just store it directly in the `map`?

```
std::map<int, Request> myMap;
```

Then you don't need to worry at all. Just do `myMap.erase(it_req);`; no `delete` to worry about. This is actually the simplest solution, in terms of logic to think about and amount of code (but will be a slightly larger change to your existing code, probably).

If you really do need to dynamically allocate the `Request`, for whatever reason, instead of storing a raw pointer, you could store a smart pointer, which will automatically `delete` the pointed-to object when it is destroyed. The default choice for this would be [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr).

```
std::map<int, std::unique_ptr<Request>> myMap;
```

Then you again only need to do `myMap.erase(it_req);`; no manual `delete` to worry about.

Comment: replacing the order of erase and delete commands, does not help. I still have the leakage problem. I'll try the next solution.

Comment: Well the `erase()`/`delete` is the only problem in the small snippet of code you show that would cause a leak. Perhaps the specific problem you are seeing is actually elsewhere. Perhaps you need a new question, with an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can track down the actual problem. A code snippet is not enough if the problem is elsewhere.